# Mat-Autocomplete binding input to ngModel

Tags: angular, angular-material

All the example of the Angular Material Autocomplete do not show how you would use it being bound to an object via ngModel

Here is what I have in my HTML

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="w-100 tableInput">
      <input matInput type="text" 
           [ngModel]="model.name"
           [formControl]="startTimeLineDefinitionControl" 
           [matAutocomplete]="auto">
        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
              <mat-option *ngFor="let lineCrossingDefinition of filteredLineCrossingDefinitions | async" 
                 [value]="lineCrossingDefinition.name"
                 (click)="onStartTimeLineDefinitionSelect(lineCrossingDefinition)">
                      {{lineCrossingDefinition.name}}</mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

My TS file

```
startTimeLineDefinitionControl = new FormControl()

// Setup StartTimeLineDefinition Filter
    this.filteredLineCrossingDefinitions = this.startTimeLineDefinitionControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(value => { 
        return this._lineCrossingDefinitionsFilter(value)
      }),
    );

private _lineCrossingDefinitionsFilter(value: string): LineCrossingDefinition[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

    return this.lineCrossingDefinitions.filter(lineCrossingDefinition => lineCrossingDefinition.name.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
  }
```

The issue that I am coming across is that when binding the input via ngModel the value is set and then its changed via the formControl.  The console shows the following errors

"It looks like you are using ngModel on the same form field as formControl. Support for using the ngModel input property and ngModelChange event with reactive form directives has been deprecated in Angular v6"

"NG0100 ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError"

What I am looking for is an input box that is bound to a models property. When the user types in the input box it will show the dropdown of values that match the current inputs value. If the user selects an item from the dropdown, the input is set to that value and so is the model property.

Why is that so difficult? Please tell me im just missing something simple

Comment: The most of examples of material not include a [(ngModel)] or the use by a FromControl, but you can use like if you're using a simple input (think about they like a custom formControl). But rememeber, if use reactiveForms (formControlName or FormControl) **not** use [ngModel] -and vice versa-